# Parse OS X SDK Skipping Code After Calling "save" on PFObject

Tags: objective-c, macos, parse-platform

I'm trying to update a PFObject that already exists in the cloud by performing a query, adjusting the retrieved object, and then saving it. I initially tried this with the saveInBackgroundWithBlock method, but the block never got called. I moved the save method afterwards, and any code after the save call does not get executed.

I'm running Yosemite with the newest Parse OS X SDK.

```
-(void)saveCardToCloud:(Card *)card{
if(card.cardID){
    PFQuery *cardQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Card"];
    [cardQuery whereKey:@"cardID" equalTo:card.cardID];
    [cardQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            if ([objects count] > 0) {
                PFObject *retrievedObject = [objects firstObject];
                retrievedObject[@"lastSeenAt"] = card.lastSeenAt;
                if(!retrievedObject[@"firstSeenAt"]){
                    retrievedObject[@"firstSeenAt"] = card.firstSeenAt;
                }
                retrievedObject[@"officeCheckIns"] = card.officeCheckIns;
                retrievedObject[@"shopCheckIns"] = card.shopCheckIns;
                [retrievedObject save];
                NSLog(@"SAVED IT");
                [retrievedObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                    if(!error){
                        NSLog(@"Updated existing card");
                    }else{
                        NSLog(@"Failed to update existing card: %@", error);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

}

[image: Parse Issue GIF]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting one of the keys on the PFObject to nil, but Parse wasn't throwing an exception. Fix:

```
if(card.officeCheckIns) retrievedObject[@"officeCheckIns"] = card.officeCheckIns;
if(card.shopCheckIns) retrievedObject[@"shopCheckIns"] = card.shopCheckIns;
```